# fuzzy string compare (check for shorthand matching) C#

Tags: c#, string, fuzzy-comparison

I have two lists of string, and I want to extract from each list the index if the string at current index is in the second list(and vice versa), the string cant match exactly or can be a shorthand of another list, for example, consider this two list

```
List<string> aList = new List<string> { "Id", "PartCode", "PartName", "EquipType" };
List<string> bList = new List<string> { "PartCode", "PartName", "PartShortName", "EquipmentType" };
```

in the above example, I want from `aList` the indexes: 1,2,3

and from `bList` indexes 0,1,3

indexes 1,2 from `aList` are obvious the string matched completely, but the interesting part are *"EquipType"* and *"EquipmentType"*  which **match** becuse *"EquipType"*  is a shorthand of *"EquipmentType"*

but *"PartName"* is **not a shorthand** of *"PartShortName"* so there indexes are not needed

these is my code

```
List<string> aList = new List<string> { "Id", "PartCode", "PartName", "EquipType" };// 1, 2 , 3
List<string> bList = new List<string> { "PartCode", "PartName", "PartShortName", "EquipmentType" };//0, 1 ,3 

List<int> alistIndex = new List<int>();
List<int> blistIndex = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count; i++)           
{
    string a = aList[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < bList.Count(); j++)               
    {
        string b = bList[j];

        string bigger, smaller;
        int biggerCount, smallerCount;
        if (a.Length > b.Length)
        {
            bigger = a; smaller = b;
            biggerCount = a.Length ; smallerCount = b.Length ;    
        }
        else
        {
            bigger = b; smaller = a;
            biggerCount = b.Length; smallerCount = a.Length ;
        }

        int countCheck = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < biggerCount; k++)
        {
            if (smaller.Length != countCheck)
            {
                if (bigger[k] == smaller[countCheck])
                    countCheck++;
             }
         }

        if (countCheck == smaller.Length)
        {
            alistIndex.Add(i);
            blistIndex.Add(j);
            res = true;
            break;
        }
        else
            res = false;  
    }
}

alistIndex.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i));
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
blistIndex.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i));
Console.ReadKey();
```

the above code works just fine and looks very similar to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840503/how-to-compare-2-strings-and-find-the-difference-in-percentage#answer-16840829)

but if change the order of the second list like so

```
 List<string> bList = new List<string> { "PartCode", "PartShortName", "PartName", "EquipmentType" };
```

i will get index 0,  1 and 3 (but i want 0 2 and 3)

should i check the distance for every pair and return the lowest? or should i work i a different method

Thanks

p.s
i also found [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=fuzzystring) GitHub, but i don't know if it will do the trick for me

Comment: Do you assume that "EquipType" and "EquipmentType" is same?

Comment: @L_J what do you mean?

Comment: please double check your examples and indexs, i could swear your contradicting yourself. Also be clear what you mean, you can not have it work in one case and not the other for shorthand... as per @L_J question. hes trying to get clarity on what you are wanting as it doesn't appear to be clear.

Comment: @Seabizkit maybe shorthand is not the right word to describe what I want but maybe "abbreviation" would be more suitable (as U.S and united states, so are EquipType and EquipmentType but not PartName PartShortName)
Am i more clear now?

Comment: Question is really about how to compare two strings. After that, comparing of lists is trivial. So, what are the exact criteria when you consider two strings being the "same"?

Comment: I feel that matching for example *Id* with *Idiotic* or *Foo* with *Foolish* would be quite strange :-) But it is what you are trying to do. Especially with short words like Id, there can be many matches that have totally different meaning while starting in the same why... It reminds me of persons that that tried to use regexes to match "bad" words, then discovering that *ass* was part o amb*ass*ador, c*ass*ette, *ass*umption...

Answer (score 2):

I do feel that what you are trying to do is a bad idea... *Id* is the abbreviation of *Idiotic*, just to give an example :-) Still... I wanted to do some experiments on Unicode.

Now, this code will split words on uppercase letters. `PartName` is `Part + Name` because the `N` is uppercase. It doesn't support `ID` as `Identifier` (because it should be `IDentifier`) but it does support `NSA` as `NotSuchAgency` :-) So full acronyms are ok, while `FDA` isn't equivalent to `FoodAndDrugAdministration`, so acronyms with conjunctions are KO.

```
public static bool ShorthandCompare(string str1, string str2)
{
    if (str1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str1));
    }

    if (str2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str2));
    }

    if (str1 == string.Empty)
    {
        return str2 == string.Empty;
    }

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2))
    {
        return true;
    }

    var ee1 = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(str1);
    var ee2 = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(str2);

    bool eos1, eos2 = true;

    while ((eos1 = ee1.MoveNext()) && (eos2 = ee2.MoveNext()))
    {
        string ch1 = ee1.GetTextElement(), ch2 = ee2.GetTextElement();

        // The string.Compare does some nifty tricks with unicode
        // like string.Compare("ì", "i\u0300") == 0
        if (string.Compare(ch1, ch2) == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        UnicodeCategory uc1 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch1, 0);
        UnicodeCategory uc2 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch2, 0);

        if (uc1 == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
        {
            while (uc2 != UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter && (eos2 = ee2.MoveNext()))
            {
                ch2 = ee2.GetTextElement();
                uc2 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch2, 0);
            }

            if (!eos2 || string.Compare(ch1, ch2) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            continue;
        }
        else if (uc2 == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
        {
            while (uc1 != UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter && (eos1 = ee1.MoveNext()))
            {
                ch1 = ee1.GetTextElement();
                uc1 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch1, 0);
            }

            if (!eos1 || string.Compare(ch1, ch2) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            continue;
        }

        // We already know they are different!
        return false;
    }

    if (eos1)
    {
        while (ee1.MoveNext())
        {
            string ch1 = ee1.GetTextElement();
            UnicodeCategory uc1 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch1, 0);

            if (uc1 == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (eos2)
    {
        while (ee2.MoveNext())
        {
            string ch2 = ee2.GetTextElement();
            UnicodeCategory uc2 = char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch2, 0);

            if (uc2 == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

and then

```
List<string> aList = new List<string> { "Id", "PartCode", "PartName", "EquipType" };
List<string> bList = new List<string> { "PartCode", "PartName", "PartShortName", "EquipmentType" };

List<List<int>> matches = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count; i++)
{
    var lst = new List<int>();
    matches.Add(lst);

    for (int j = 0; j < bList.Count; j++)
    {
        if (ShorthandCompare(aList[i], bList[j]))
        {
            lst.Add(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the result is a `List<List<int>>`, because you could have multiple matches for a single word of `aList`!

Now... the interesting part of the `ShorthandCompare` is that it tries to be "intelligent" and handle non-BMP Unicode characters (through the use of `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator`) and handle decomposed Unicode characters (the `ì` character can be obtained in Unicode through `i` + `\u0300`, that is its dieresis). It does it through the use of `string.Compare` that, differently than `string.Equals`, is Unicode-aware (`string.CompareOrdinal` is more similar to `string.Equals` and not Unicode-aware).

```
bool cmp1 = ShorthandCompare("IdìoLe\u0300ss", "Idi\u0300oticLèsser"); // true
```